# Fields of QuerySet are not accessible from views.py in Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to create a track report since past two weeks in which I'm constantly failing. I have 3 models, `Student`, `Course` and `Fee`. I want to create a report which will bring all the data contained by these 3 models, together, with an ID of its own.

The models:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    roll_number=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=60)
    city=models.CharField(max_length=20)

class CourseChoices(models.Model):
    courses=models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.courses

class Course(models.Model):
    roll_number=models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=CASCADE)
    course=models.ForeignKey(CourseChoices, on_delete=CASCADE)

class Fee(models.Model):
    roll_number=models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=CASCADE)
    amount_to_be_paid=models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    discount=models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    Final_amount_to_be_paid=models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    Amount_received=models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    Balance=models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    batch=models.IntegerField()
```

Now, a student may pay his/her fee in installments, so that will create multiple instances in the track report. I want the user to track each transaction with the primary key/id. Below is an example:

[image: Sample track report]

One member here suggested me to create another model named Report:

```
class Report(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=7, primary_key=True)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fee = models.ForeignKey(Fee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def _get_next_id(self):
        last = self.objects.aggregate(max_id=models.Max('id'))['max_id']
        if last is None:
            last = 1
        self.id = "{}{:04d}".format('HB', last)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.id = self._get_next_id()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

And then when the transaction happens - I save an additional instance of Report that contains links to other objects.

```
Report.objects.create(student=student, fee=fee, course=course)
```

So I wrote a view for fee as below:

```
def fee_view(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        fm_fee=FeeForm(request.POST)
        if fm_fee.is_valid():
            fm_fee.save()
            fee=Fee.objects.all()
            print()
            print(fee)
            print()
            print(fee[1])
            Report.objects.create(student=fee.roll_number, fee=fee, course=Course.objects.get(roll_number=fee.roll_number))
            fm_fee=FeeForm()
        return render(request, 'account/fee.html', {'form1':fm_fee})
    else:
        fm_fee=FeeForm()
        return render(request, 'account/fee.html', {'form1':fm_fee})
```

The QuerySet here doesn't contain the fields somehow. When I print it, it returns:

```
<QuerySet [<Fee: Fee object (1)>, <Fee: Fee object (2)>, <Fee: Fee object (3)>, <Fee: Fee object (4)>, <Fee: Fee object (5)>, <Fee: Fee object (6)>, <Fee: Fee object (7)>, <Fee: Fee object (8)>, <Fee: Fee object (9)>, <Fee: Fee object (10)>, <Fee: Fee object (11)>, <Fee: Fee object (12)>, <Fee: Fee object (13)>, <Fee: Fee object (14)>]>
```

The Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/fee/

Django Version: 3.2.6
Python Version: 3.9.6
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'account']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "F:\Sonu\Projects\Practice\test1\account\views.py", line 48, in fee_view
    Report.objects.create(student=fee.roll_number, fee=fee, course=Course.objects.get(roll_number=fee.roll_number))

Exception Type: AttributeError at /fee/
Exception Value: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'roll_number'
```

**EDIT 1:**

New view:

```
def fee_view(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        fm_fee=FeeForm(request.POST)
        if fm_fee.is_valid():
            fee=fm_fee.save()
            print()
            print(fee)
            print()
            print(fee.roll_number)
            Report.objects.create(student=fee.roll_number, fee=fee, course=Course.objects.get(roll_number=fee.roll_number))
            fm_fee=FeeForm()
        return render(request, 'account/fee.html', {'form1':fm_fee})
    else:
        fm_fee=FeeForm()
        return render(request, 'account/fee.html', {'form1':fm_fee})
```

Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/fee/

Django Version: 3.2.6
Python Version: 3.9.6
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'account']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "F:\Sonu\Projects\Practice\test1\account\views.py", line 50, in fee_view
    Report.objects.create(student=fee.roll_number, fee=fee, course=Course.objects.get(roll_number=fee.roll_number))
  File "C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 453, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "F:\Sonu\Projects\Practice\test1\account\models.py", line 51, in save
    self.id = self._get_next_id()
  File "F:\Sonu\Projects\Practice\test1\account\models.py", line 44, in _get_next_id
    last = self.objects.aggregate(max_id=models.Max('id'))['max_id']
  File "C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 179, in __get__
    raise AttributeError("Manager isn't accessible via %s instances" % cls.__name__)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /fee/
Exception Value: Manager isn't accessible via Report instances
```

**EDIT 2:**

Report model:

```
class Report(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=7, primary_key=True)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fee = models.ForeignKey(Fee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def _get_next_id(self):
        last = Report.objects.aggregate(max_id=models.Max('id'))['max_id']
        if last is None:
            last = 1
        self.id = "{}{:04d}".format('HB', last)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.id = self._get_next_id()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I replaced `self` with `Report` but I now get a ValueError, the Traceback is here:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/fee/

Django Version: 3.2.6
Python Version: 3.9.6
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'account']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "F:\Sonu\Projects\Practice\test1\account\views.py", line 50, in fee_view
    Report.objects.create(student=fee.roll_number, fee=fee, course=Course.objects.get(roll_number=fee.roll_number))
  File "C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 453, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "F:\Sonu\Projects\Practice\test1\account\models.py", line 51, in save
    self.id = self._get_next_id()
  File "F:\Sonu\Projects\Practice\test1\account\models.py", line 47, in _get_next_id
    self.id = "{}{:04d}".format('HB', last)

Exception Type: ValueError at /fee/
Exception Value: Unknown format code 'd' for object of type 'str'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `fee=Fee.objects.all()` you're getting all of your `Fee` objects, so you can't then access a field from `fee`.

If you're looking to create a report from the saved fee form, you likely want to do;

```
       if fm_fee.is_valid():
            fee = fm_fee.save()

            Report.objects.create(
                student=fee.roll_number,
                fee=fee,
                course=Course.objects.get(roll_number=fee.roll_number)
            )
            fm_fee=FeeForm()
```

This assumes that `FeeForm` is a `ModelForm` so that saving it will create a `Fee` instance.

Going back to your queryset, `fees = Fee.objects.all()`, you could access a column on the table by doing something like `fees.values_list('roll_number', flat=True)`.

This would give you a list of all the `roll_number` values in the `Fee` table.

*edit*

Looks like your error is caused by:

`last = self.objects.aggregate(max_id=models.Max('id'))['max_id']`

Where it says;

> Manager isn't accessible via Report instances

I assume that `self` is an instance of a report, so it can't do `.objects`. You'd need to do `Report.objects.aggregate` here.

Comment: It now gives me another AttributeError at /fee/. I have pasted the code in Edit 1 in my question. Please have a look at it.

Comment: @noob87 that's some other code that's not included here, but I've tried to explain hat is likely going on there.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. I have pasted that particular code in the Edit 2. I also replaced the self with Report there but I now get a ValueError.

Comment: The ValueError issue is solved now. Could you please tell me why the code below doesn't return the value that is intended? Instead the id simply turns out to be the default 1, 2, 3 and so on. Any suggestions?

Comment: @noob87 It's difficult to say, but it's a separate issue to that which this question addressed. I'd ask another question, including your models, your custom `save()` an `_get_next_id()` which is causing the problem.

Comment: Alright. Thanks for your guidance, Mark. Means a lot. I'll try and work on those methods. :)